# How can I copy each worksheet into a new workbook and preserve formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

As in my title.. I have the following code:

```
Sub SaveSheets(yeard, monthd)
Dim strPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & yeard & "\"
If Len(Dir(strPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (strPath)
End If
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & yeard & "\" & monthd & "\"
If Len(Dir(strPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (strPath)
End If

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    BreakLinks Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close True, strPath & ws.Name & " DATASET " & monthd & " " & yeard & ".xlsx"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub BreakLinks(wb As Workbook)
    Dim lnk As Variant
    For Each lnk In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wb.BreakLink lnk, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next
End Sub
```

But the problem is the worksheet is copying without preserving the source formatting. Is there a way of maintaining this code and adding in something small extra to get what I want? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what formatting is not preserved, but I manually copied one sheet to a new workbook and the formatting was copied properly (your code should work)

Or you can try the following which saves each sheet as a separate .xlsm:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub saveWS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.SaveAs ws.Name, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Strangely enough, doing a plain rightclick on worksheet and move/copy to new workbook completely messes up the formatting too. I think the VBA code may actually not be the culprit. Thanks for setting me on this path, I will delve a little deeper!

Comment: There is definitely something else wrong to be fixed; try disabling all Add-Ins at startup; if you didn't install any add-ins try repairing the Office installation

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new workbook and then copying each sheet into it, why not just save the workbook with a new name?

Comment: This will be perfect unless each sheet is to be its own workbook

Comment: Yes unfortunately each worksheet has to be its own workbook